# why can't I use fill_value when adding a dataframe and a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

for example:

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1, 2, np.nan), (6, 5)))
s = pd.Series(range(5))
s[3] = np.nan
df.add(s, fill_value=0)
```

this code will return :

```
NotImplementedError: fill_value 0 not supported.
```

my question is:

1. `fill_value` means fill the value of `df` and `s` before the calculation, or fill the value of the result after adding `df` and `s`?
2. why this code wrong?
   Is it because it's the calculation between a dataframe and a series so I can't use `fill_value`? but why?

Comment: It is a NotImplemented [Issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13488). you can either use `df.fillna(0).add(s)`  or ask re-raise an issue on the pandas github

Comment: Where does this code come from? It's curious that is almost the exact same code as in the duplicate from 2016

Comment: @Brian61354270 it is ; hasn't been implemented since then I suppose

Comment: @SurajShourie my question was to the OP